# Can't connect to WP-Admin, blank error message

Tags: wp-admin, login

I have to work on a website, but I cannot connect to the WordPress Administration... I did a forget password and resetted the password multiple times so I know that I have the right username/password combination, but I still cannot connect.

Anytime I try to connect, it comes back to the wp-login page with a blank error message.

Tried to update my WP installation, didn't fix the problem (site is now running WP 4.2.2)

The blank message appears with both a correct and incorrect login.

I have no idea what might cause this problem, can somebody help?

[image]

Comment: Disable your plugins and switch themes to a core theme -- a Twenty-Something one. Can you log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if your `functions.php` file includes a filter for `login_errors`.

For example, this would disable any login errors from being displayed:

```
add_filter('login_errors', function($error){ return null; });
```

This is sometimes done as a security measure so the reason a login attempt failed isn't available to any would-be hacker or bot.

More info on this filter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_errors

Comment: That was exactly that! Now to see why I cant login at all.